# Duplicating a javascript Object and then modify it without changing the original instance?

Tags: javascript, oop

```
Order.prototype.selectItem = function(newItem) { ...
```

`newItem` is the object I want to copy and then modify the copy without modifying the original newItem.

```
var newSelectedItem = newItem;
newSelectedItem.orderIndex = this.selectedItems.length + 1;
```

Changing the orderIndex of the copy will also change the original newItem.

**Question:** How do I copy and then modify the copy without modifying the original newItem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using jQuery (which I'd suggest), you can clone objects per this post:
[What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)

Comment: By the way, please note the person who answered that question.  :)

Comment: This was perfect! Answers from John Resig are always nice! Below is what I ended up using:

// Deep copy
var newObject = jQuery.extend(true, {}, oldObject);

Answer (score 2):

Create a new object

```
var newSelectedItem = {};
```

And copy all properties from the old object into the new one

```
for(var prop in newItem){
    if(newItem.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
        newSelectedItem[prop] = newItem[prop];
    }
}
```

Note that this solution only works for plain objects that are flat. If "newItem" is an instance of some prototype you cannot just create the new object with `{}` and if properties can contain mutable arrays or objects then you also need to do a recursive deep copy.

For more examples, the dojo toolkit has some functions (mixin and clone) for doing this kind of thing: http://trac.dojotoolkit.org/browser/dojo/dojo/trunk/_base/lang.js

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to clone the object.  If all you want to do is have an object you can set properties on without altering the original, the so-called "Boodman/[Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html) delegation" is far more efficient.  Wishing I had published that when I first used it :)  See also [dojo.delegate](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dojo/delegate)